# Nested attributes with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing a system to improve my Rails skills, which will allow anyone to create a user.  This user will have an inventory, which will contain multiple items.

My question is how can I store all the resources when saving a new user. I'm trying to use `cocoon` gem, and I got this error message:

```
undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass
```

at this part of the code:

```
<%= link_to_remove_association "remove item", f %>
```

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :inventory

  delegate :items, to: :inventory, prefix: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventory
end

class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inventory_items
  has_many :items, through: :inventory_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventory_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :inventory
end
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new.tap do |user|
      user.inventory = Inventory.new
      user.inventory_items.build
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params
      .require(:user)
      .permit(
        :name,
        :lat,
        :long,
        :age,
        inventory_attributes: [:id, inventory_items_attributes: [:quantity, :inventory_id, :item_id, :_destroy]]
      )
  end
end
```

**User form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :lat %>
    <%= f.input :long %>
  </div>

  <h3>Items</h3>
  <div id="inventory_items">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :inventory do |inventory| %>
      <%= inventory.simple_fields_for :inventory_items do |f| %>
        <%= render 'item_fields', f: f %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**item_fields partial**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.collection_select :item_id, Item.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.input :quantity %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove item", f %>
</div>
```

The inventory does not have more attributes than its `id` and `user_id`

**Stack trace**

```
cocoon (1.2.9) lib/cocoon/view_helpers.rb:29:in `link_to_remove_association'
app/views/users/_inventory_item_fields.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users__inventory_item_fields_html_erb__1201857070210368281_70056778972140'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
app/views/users/new.html.erb:12:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___3186868675472137201_70056772986280'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:714:in `fields_for'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1599:in `fields_for'
simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/builder.rb:27:in `simple_fields_for'
app/views/users/new.html.erb:11:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___3186868675472137201_70056772986280'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1925:in `block in fields_for_nested_model'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:714:in `fields_for'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1924:in `fields_for_nested_model'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1914:in `fields_for_with_nested_attributes'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1582:in `fields_for'
simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/builder.rb:27:in `simple_fields_for'
app/views/users/new.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___3186868675472137201_70056772986280'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:26:in `block in simple_form_for'
simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:45:in `with_simple_form_field_error_proc'
simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:25:in `simple_form_for'
app/views/users/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___3186868675472137201_70056772986280'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/vinicius/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
```

Comment: Where exactly you got that error? Can you update your question with full error stack?

Comment: i got that error at `item_fields` partial

Comment: You're passing the form object as *f* but you're accessimg it as *item* inside of the item_fields partial.

Comment: Your're right @michalvalasek. but this was an older version of the code. i've updated it now. Do you think that those relations are correct?

Comment: @ViníciusVenanciodosSantos Well, that's a bit hard to tell since I don't know much about the thing you're trying to model. It looks a little overcomplicated to me. I would expect just the User-Inventory-Item hierarchy. Other than that it looks OK.

Comment: @michalvalasek, User-Inventory-Item it is exactly what i'm trying to model. Actually, User-Inventory-Items seems to be correct, because it's a has_many through relation. But i can find the error, it looks okay for me. :(

Comment: @ViníciusVenanciodosSantos What are the cardinalities of the relations?

Comment: @michalvalasek, User has one inventory, inventory has many items through inventory items, and items has many inventories through inventory_items. I hope you can understand this kk

Comment: @ViníciusVenanciodosSantos Does that mean that a User can have many Items and an item can belong to many Users? If so you can get rid of both Inventory and InventoryItem models. Just create has_and_belongs_to_many relation betwen User and Item model (both ways) and you should be fine.

Comment: @michalvalasek the question is that the inventory is necessary. So i can't remove those associations